# For loop in which each iteration is done after a certain amount of seconds

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, time

Such a question probably exists, but I could not find what I am looking for. What I want to do is:
Consider this for loop

```
import time
for i in range(steps):
   print('Step {}'.format(i))
```

by importing `time`, how can I make the for loop iterate each step for x seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sleep` to wait exactly 1 second.

```
import time
for i in range(steps):
   time.sleep(1)
   print('Step {}'.format(i))
```

Comment: does it work for float numbers smaller than 1? (milliseconds)